# How do I show all the Users that are part of a Group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, model-associations, partials

What I want to do is show the Users that are members of a Group. I have 3 models: Users, Membership, & Groups. I would like to show all the Users that are "members" of a Group. I think my problem has to do with my Groups controller.

**Here is each of the models attributes:**

```
create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
end

create_table "memberships", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "group_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
end
```

**Here is the code in each respective model:**

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

**Here is the code in the controller for Groups:**

```
class CirclesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @membership = Membership.where(group_id: @group)
  end
end
```

**Here is the code in the View for Groups**

```
<h1>Group Name: <%= @group.name %></h1>
<div class="row">
   <%= render @memberships %>
</div>
```

**Here is the code in the partial _membership.html.erb**

Ideally I would like to show the Users First Name & Last Name, but for now I would be happy at least showing the Members User_ID. Thank you in advance for your help!

*As a side note, if I change my code in the View for Groups to the code below then I can see the 2 users that are members of that group*

```
<h1>Group Name: <%= @group.name %></h1>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <table>

          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Member ID</th>
              <th>Group ID</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <% @membership.each do |member| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= member.user_id %></td>
                <td><%= member.circle_id %></td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your specific struggle at the moment? What error do you receive or what exactly you want explained?

Comment: `Group.find(params[:id]).users` should return the users belonging to this Group. From there you can easily loop on the returned users and use it in your views

Comment: Thank you both @EugZol and @MrYoshiji! I was able to solve my challenge of showing the Users who are part of a group.

Answer (score 2):

**Controller**

```
class CirclesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @members = @group.users # this will find the group users
  end
end
```

**partial**

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= member.id %></td> // it will show the user ID
      <td><%= @group.id %></td> // I assume your circle_id is the group id
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you @Emu! I am now able to show the users of any group.